# std::set: Using iterator causes memory violation exception

Tags: c++, iterator, stdset

I have below code. The code doesn't work in Visual Studio. But in another compiler, such as onlinegdb.com, it works fine. And output "

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set <int> ms{1,2,3,4,5};
    set <int>::iterator it;

    int i = 0;
    for (it = ms.begin(); it != ms.end(); ++it) {
        if (i == 4)  {
            ms.erase(it);               // I know if I want to remove the last element, I can just code "ms.erase(--ms.end())" without the need of a loop
            // it = ms.erase(it);       // replacing the above link with this line doesn't work neither
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (auto x : ms) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

- If run on onlinegdb.com: `1 2 3 4`
- If run on Visual Studio 2019, error `Expression: cannot increment value-initialized map/set iterator`

I think when the last element is removed, iterator `it` will be set as `end`. So the loop will break.

Can anyone explain for me why stuff cannot work in Visual Studio? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Erasing the element invalidates the iterator. Using the iterator returned from `erase` is the right thing to do, but that iterator references the element past the one erased, hence you should only increment when you do not erase:

```
for (it = ms.begin(); it != ms.end(); ) {   // do not increment here
    if (i == 4)  {            
        it = ms.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;                               // but only when you do not erase
    }
    ++i;
}
```

For more details on iterator invalidation I refer you to [Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers).

Comment: You don't need `++it` in the `for()`.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* use what the `erase` function [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase#Return_value).

And if you erase you should *not* increase the iterator.

Comment: Also, `ms.erase (4)` would work here.